# Xamarin Form: Android using Firebase Cloud Messaging not receiving message

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have made the Firebase Cloud Message Notification working even work through the Notification Hub from Azure. The time I can't receive the message is when I try to re-run the application.

Process:
1) Fresh install the application with Visual Studio IDE
2) Stop the debugger
3) Debug and run the application again through Visual Studio IDE
4) Send a test message through FCM Console

If I am not doing 3, I still can receive the message even if the application is in background

```
   LoadApplication(new App());

            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .SetApplicationId(GetString(Resource.String.fcmAppId))
            .SetApiKey(GetString(Resource.String.fcmApiKey))
            .SetGcmSenderId(GetString(Resource.String.fcmGCMSenderId))
            .Build();

            FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Android.App.Application.Context, options);
```

?

```
    public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseInstanceIdService";

    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        Settings.NotificationToken = refreshedToken;
        Android.Util.Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
    {
    }
}
```

Initially I thought it has a different token but is the same.

Message from Azure Portal:

The token obtained from the token provider is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Android using Firebase Cloud Messaging not receiving message

As the [GCM docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#key) said :

> An ID issued by the GCM connection servers to the client app that allows it to receive messages.

So only when the token is available, your app can receive message from `GCM`.

How can an app get that token?

You could see [the document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) :

> On initial startup of your app, the FCM SDK generates a registration token for the client app instance. If you want to target single devices or create device groups, you'll need to access this token.
>
> The onTokenRefreshcallback fires whenever a new token is generated, so calling getToken in its context ensures that you are accessing a current, available registration token. Make sure you have added the service to your manifest, **then call getToken in the context of onTokenRefresh**

**Every time when you re-run the application in your device the token is changed**, but as the [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/#Implement_the_Firebase_Instance_ID_Service) said, `OnTokenRefresh` is only called when the system determines that the tokens need to be refreshed,  it is needed for key rotation and to handle Instance ID changes due to :

- **When the app is installed or uninstalled**.
- **When the user deletes app data**.
- **When the app erases the Instance ID**.
- **When the security of the token has been compromised**.

**You need to trigger `OnTokenRefresh` method**. You should first uninstall the app from the device, then reinstall the app and open it, the `OnTokenRefresh` will be triggered and the token will be updated and your app could receive `GCM` message again.