# Azure Notification Hub losing the subscribe when app is reinstalled

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I have a problem with Azure Notification Hub.

When my app is started in first time, the notifications working correctly, but when did a rebuild the app by Visual Studio, the notifications stop working and the Android Services with IntentFilters do not are called.

For the notifications works again, I need to uninstall the App in Android and run by Visual Studio again.

Have someone some idea about that problem?

My worry is: if I send the app to GooglePlay, the notifications would continue working after a update?

If someone know how to call the service to get the new InstallationId, always that the app to be started I will know how I can resolve the problem.

Can someone help me?

I did follow that tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=le2lDY22xwM&t=3312s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I send the app to GooglePlay, the notifications would continue working after a update?

**There is no need to worry about that**, referring to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started), when you use `Azure Notification Hub`, it's using Android `GCM` to send the push notificcation. You could see my answer about [Android using Firebase Cloud Messaging not receiving message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46800477/xamarin-form-android-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-not-receiving-message/46824685#46824685).

As the [Official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) said :

> On initial startup of your app, the FCM SDK generates a registration token for the client app instance. If you want to target single devices or create device groups, you'll need to access this token.

Explanation about `Token` :

> An ID issued by the GCM connection servers to the client app that allows it to receive messages.

**When you did a rebuild the app by `Visual Studio` your token is changed, but it didn't trigger the  `OnTokenRefresh` method, so at this time the `Token` in your application is invalid**. That's why your application cannot receiving message.

For more information, you could refer to [Sending Push Notifications from Azure Mobile Apps](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/push-notifications/azure/) and [Implement the Firebase Instance ID Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/).

When your app get a update, it will trigger the  `OnTokenRefresh` method automatically, so your application can still receive the message.