# Firebase message not working after app released to google playstore

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, notifications

I have implemented firebase messaging in xamarin android ,,and it works great , but soon after i release this app to play store ,  there is no notifications anymore. I have not  updated anyting in code

Comment: Is your app crashing?

Comment: No , works perfect, but no notification receieved, but still recieve in the debug version

Comment: You could refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46800477/xamarin-form-android-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-not-receiving-message/46824685#46824685

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?